# Matching string with LIKE derived from sub-query

Tags: mysql

Here is my query Where I want to match a string with a subquery output. But it is returning wrong result. What I am doing wrong? The concat part is not working as I try to run

```
Concat('"', (SELECT sec_dep 
                                  FROM   admin_users 
                                  WHERE  uid = 11), '"')
```

this part only. it shows error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   issues
WHERE  ( assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"', (SELECT sec_dep 
                              FROM   admin_users 
                              WHERE  uid = 11), '"') 
              OR assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"%,', (SELECT sec_dep 
                                FROM   admin_users 
                                WHERE  uid = 11), '"') 
              OR assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"', (SELECT sec_dep 
                              FROM   admin_users 
                              WHERE  uid = 11), ',%"') 
              OR assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"%,', (SELECT sec_dep 
                                FROM   admin_users 
                                WHERE  uid = 11), ',%"') )
```

thanx in advance.

**UPDATE**

admin_users Table

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_users` (
 `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pri_dep` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sec_dep` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

issue table

```
CREATE TABLE `issues` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `assigned_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `assigned_to_users` text,
 `assigned_to_dept` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that you are getting no results returned? **Always** include your error text with questions here.

I input your table structures (+1 for providing the DDL BTW!):

### issues:

```
mysql> DESC issues;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title             | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assigned_by       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| assigned_to_users | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assigned_to_dept  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### admin_users:

```
mysql> DESC admin_users;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pri_dep | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sec_dep | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I inputted some data:

```
INSERT INTO `issues` VALUES (1,'title1','desc1',1,'users1',3),
(2,'title10','desc10',1,'users10',10),(3,'title11','desc11',1,
'users10',11),(4,'title12','desc12',1,'users10',12),
(5,'title13','desc13',1,'users10',13);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO `admin_users` VALUES (1,9,'adsafsd'),(2,10,'zxvzvx'),
(3,11,'cgffdf'),(4,12,'iopouu'),(5,11,'adsafsd'),(9,15,'xver'),
(11,11,'waerwaer'),(12,15,'wcvvver');
```

I ran your query and it returns the empty set.

To check, I then ran the subquery that recurs:

```
SELECT sec_dep 
FROM   admin_users 
WHERE  uid = 11;
```

and the result was:

```
+----------+
| sec_dep  |
+----------+
| waerwaer |
+----------+
```

But, from `DESC issues` above, you have `assigned_to_dept` is an `INT`, so they can never match. You need to rethink your schema and/or query.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve that query significantly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM issues i, admin_users u
WHERE u.uid = 11 AND 
      (i.assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"', u.sec_dep, '"') 
       OR i.assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"%,', u.sec_dep, '"') 
       OR i.assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"', u.sec_dep, ',%"') 
       OR i.assigned_to_dept LIKE Concat('"%,', u.sec_dep, ',%"') )
```

Simpler queries are easier to debug!